# custom octagon in CSS - unable to set tranparency

Tags: html, css

**Hi there,**

I'm unable to set transparent background for this octagon created using CSS.

```
#octagon { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: red; 
    position: relative; 
}

#octagon:before { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 42px; 
    height: 0;
    border-left: 29px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 29px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;  
}

#octagon:after { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 42px; 
    height: 0;
    border-left: 29px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 29px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 29px solid red;  
}
```

Is there any way I could make it work?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using transparent, use your background color.

So for example if your background color is white use #fff.

```
#octagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

#octagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #fff;/* <--- */
    border-right: 29px solid #fff;/* <--- */
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}

#octagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #fff;/* <--- */
    border-right: 29px solid #fff; /* <--- */
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gKvpT/1/)**

---

**Alternatively**, you could use `transforms` to make an octagon

```
#octagon {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100px;
}
#octagon:after {
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jXK5C/1/)**

Comment: Yes, because using "transparent" one gets the octagon's background color that is red.

Comment: @Wracker - I updated the answer with vendor prefixes for other browsers

Comment: Ahh it does work in FF too, just had to change it to -moz-transform... Thanks!

Comment: What FF version are you using ?  FF needed prefix in version 15 and current is 28 ....